wire:snapshot with html instead json in livewire
I'm having problems with a livewire component. There is  html in the wire:snapshot attribute it is supposed to contain just json:
<ul wire:snapshot="{&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;p_padre_id&quot;:null,&quot;padre_id&quot;:null,&quot;nombre&quot;:null},&quot;memo&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;90oEN4IAMckvWYwyQF4V&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;admin.categorias&quot;,&quot;path&quot;:&quot;admin\/categorias&quot;,&quot;method&quot;:&quot;GET&quot;,&quot;children&quot;:[],&quot;scripts&quot;:[],&quot;assets&quot;:[],&quot;errors&quot;:[],&quot;locale&quot;:&quot;es&quot;},&quot;checksum&quot;:&quot;a396038a4c9dfc85baf1f81c1e3c557058bd325570d1344426004ff64dae65d4&quot;}" wire:effects="[]" wire:id="90oEN4IAMckvWYwyQF4V"> 

I can't understand and there is no ansuers in the web.
I'm really thanksfully with yours help.
Scuse me my english!

The contents of wire:snapshot in the quoted example are just JSON, with double quotes (") encoded as HTML Entities so they can be put inside double-quoted HTML attribute

you don't see any problen then?
